# HttpServletRequest does not return null?

Tags: java, forms, tomcat

I have a form:

```
<form action='?hasScenario=1' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
 <input type='file' name='file'/>
 <input type='submit' />
</form>
```

In tomcat 8.0 I want to do:

```
private void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    Part filePart = request.getPart("file");
    ....
}
```

In [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPart%28java.lang.String%29%20documentation)  I see I should get null if user doesn't enter any value. I havn't (intentionally) configured anything special for multipart/file uploading in web.xml or server. But instead of null I get:
     `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided`

I would like to handle nicely cases, when some parameters are not provided, how to do that? Catching and doing nothing on IllegalStateException is not nice way for me - in case of no parameter I'd like to ask user for file instead of scaring him with 'error/warning' words.

Answer (score 1):

It is a great way to find answer myself - just ask question to others :)

multipart-config in web.xml is a must. So my servlet part looks currently like:

```
<servlet>
 <description>Scenario</description>
 <servlet-name>Scenario</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>path-to-the-servlet</servlet-class>
 <multipart-config>
  <max-file-size>3145728</max-file-size>
  <max-request-size>5242880</max-request-size>
 </multipart-config>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Scenario</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/scenario</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Before calling getPart it's important to check there are any data, like with:

```
if (request.getContentType() != null)
    Part filePart = request.getPart("file");
    ...
```

And so finally filePart is null or a valid variable

Still I can't understand how have they made getParameter working in this post
[How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet) but this is different story :)

Comment: The code in that link uses an Apache upload library (that was for Tomcat 6 and older, of course it will work on newer versions as well).